# Determining whether a series converges when the series is the difference of two fractions

Tags: sequences-and-series

Problem:
Determine whether the series converges absolutely. Give a reason for the convergence or divergence of the corresponding series of absolute values.
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{3^n} $$

Answer:
Since all the terms of this series are positive, if the series converges then it converges
absolutely. We have:
\begin{align*}
a_n &= \frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{3^n} \\
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{3^n} \\
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{2^n} &= 0 \\
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{3^n} &= 0 \\
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
Since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$ the series may converge or it may diverge. I now try
the ratio test.
\begin{align*}
L &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{ a_{n+1} } { a_n } \\
L &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
 \frac{  \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{3^{n+1}} } {  \frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{3^n} } \\
 \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{3^{n+1}} &= \frac{ 3^{n+1} - 2^{n+1} }{6^{n+1}} \\
\frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{3^n} &= \frac{ 3^n - 2^n }{6^n} \\
%
L &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
 \dfrac{  \dfrac{ 3^{n+1} - 2^{n+1} }{6^{n+1}} } { \dfrac{ 3^n - 2^n }{6^n} } \\
%
L &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{ 3^{n+1} - 2^{n+1} } { 6 \left( 3^n - 2^n \right) }
\end{align*}
How do I evaluate this limit? Should I be using the Ratio Test?

Comment: Why so complicated? The sum and difference of absolutely convergent series is absolutely convergent. Or just use that $0 < \frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{3^n} < \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the response. If you post your response as an answer, I will accept it and that will close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series is convergent and we can also calculate the infinite sum.

Note that $0<\dfrac{1}{2}$,$\dfrac{1}{3}<1 \implies 0<\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)^n,\bigg(\dfrac{1}{3}\bigg)^n<1$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. So we can use the criterion for geometric series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{2^n}-\dfrac{1}{3^n}\Bigg)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^n}-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^n}=\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{2}}-\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{3}}=2-\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$